# Python PDF deconcatenation

Tags: python, pdf

I need to deconcatenate PDF using a range of page. For example, I have a 10 pages PDF and I want to keep only the page 2 to 6. For now I use the following python script to do this :

```
pdftk_args = ['pdftk']
pdftk_args.append(file)
pdftk_args.append('cat')
pdftk_args.append("%s-%s" % (page['index_start'], page['index_end']))
pdftk_args.append('output')
pdftk_args.append(page['pdf_filename'])

subprocess.check_call(pdftk_args)
```

But I want to find an alternative to avoid the use of subprocess. Is it possible to do this with a native Python library ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PyPDF2 (pip install PyPDF2)`

Assuming that you are indexing from 1 :

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

def split_pdf(input_path, output_path, pages):

    input = PdfFileReader(open(input_path, "rb"))
    output = PdfFileWriter()

    for page in pages:
        output.addPage(input.getPage(page - 1))

    with open(output_path, "wb") as stream:
        output.write(stream)
```

Usage :

```
pages = [1, 2, 3, 4] # for specific pages (1, 2, 3, 4)
pages = range(1, 5) # for a range (1, 2, 3, 4)
split_pdf("input.pdf", "output.pdf", pages)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it looks like task for [pdfrw](https://pypi.org/project/pdfrw/). Consider example:

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter
start = 2
end = 6
pages = PdfReader('inputfile.pdf').pages
outdata = PdfWriter('outputfile.pdf')
for pagenum in range(start,end+1):
    outdata.addpage(pages[pagenum-1])
outdata.write()
```

I used [this example from GitHub](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/blob/master/examples/subset.py) creating my example. I assumed that you count pdf pages starting from `1` and under pages 2 to 6 means pages `2,3,4,5,6` (i.e. including 6).